# parsing using SimpleDateFormatter

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I have a date formatted like this 2018-07-13T16:06:46+00:00. I would like to convert it to long.

I tried the following code and it gives me parse exception.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
Date dt = formatter.parse("2018-07-13T16:06:46+00:00");
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, you are using troublesome old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Comment: Thanks, @BasilBourque. I've switched my implementation to use OffsetDateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to convert it to long

It seems you have a problem with the format of your date, If you are using [**java.time**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API it can be more easier, you can just use the default format of [**OffsetDateTime**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) like this :

```
String stringDate = "2018-07-13T16:06:46+00:00";
OffsetDateTime ofset = OffsetDateTime.parse(stringDate);
Instant instant = ofset.toInstant();
long millisecond = instant.toEpochMilli();
System.out.println(millisecond);//1531498006000
```

or you can make it in one shot :

```
//parse the date and convert it to long (It seems you want to get millisecond)
long millisecond = OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-07-13T16:06:46+00:00")
                                 .toInstant()
                                 .toEpochMilli();
```

Comment: `OffsetDateTime` is appropriate here, rather than `ZonedDateTime`. The input has only a mere offset-from-UTC, not a time zone. And I suggest breaking the example code out to multiple lines for clarity.

Comment: thank you @BasilBourque, not related but do you have any good documentation to makes difference between the three `OffsetDateTime` - `ZonedDateTime` - `LocalDateTime` and where we should use each one?

Comment: The class JavaDoc does so. For a moment in UTC, `Instant`. For a moment some number of hours and minutes away from UTC, `OffsetDateTime`. For a moment adjusted into a time zone, a named history of changes in offset-from-UTC used by the people of a particular region, use `ZonedDateTime`. When you do *not* have a specific moment, only a date and a time-of-day without the context of an offset or zone, a date-time that could be applied to *any* locality or *all* localities, use `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Good explanation @BasilBourque thank you so much I really appreciate it

Comment: This answer has all the advantages. We don’t need any explicit formatter. It will work no matter if the formatted date-time has milliseconds or not. java.time is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1):

This being a standard data format in java 8 you could try:

```
ZonedDateTime parsedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-07-13T16:06:46+00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
System.out.println(parsedDateTime.toEpochSecond());
```

Comment: `OffsetDateTime` is more appropriate here than `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Can verify what @Sun has posted, as I came to the same conclusion. The following code works on my system:

```
import java.util.Date;  
import java.text.ParseException;  
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  

public class DateFormatter {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
        try {
            Date dt = formatter.parse("2018-07-13T16:06:46+00:00");
            System.out.println(dt);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```